# MySql Query Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, left-join

I generate a report using the following query in an old classic asp application using MySQL database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
  (SELECT b.rep_year,
          b.rep_month,
          sum(x.book_qty)AS salecnt,
          sum(x.book_qty*x.s_price)AS Tsales
   FROM report_date b
   LEFT JOIN sale x ON Month(x.s_Date) = b.rep_month
   AND year(x.s_Date) = b.rep_year
   WHERE x.s_date <=curdate()
     AND x.s_date >'2010-10-31'
   GROUP BY b.rep_month,
            b.rep_year)AS bob,

  (SELECT c.rep_year,
          c.rep_month,
          sum(y.gQty) AS Tgift,
          sum(y.gQty*y.gPrice)AS TGiftSum
   FROM report_date c
   LEFT JOIN gift y ON month(y.gDate) = c.rep_month
   AND year(y.gDate)=c.rep_year
   WHERE y.gbooktype =1
     AND y.gdate <=curdate()
     AND y.gdate>'2010-10-31'
   GROUP BY c.rep_year,
            c.rep_month)AS cob,

  (SELECT d.rep_year,
          d.rep_month,
          sum(z.gQty) AS Ttgift,
          sum(z.gQty*z.gprice)AS TtGiftSum
   FROM report_date d
   LEFT JOIN gift z ON month(z.gDate) = d.rep_month
   AND year(z.gDate)=d.rep_year
   WHERE z.gbooktype =2
     AND z.gdate <=curdate()
     AND z.gDate>'2010-10-31'
   GROUP BY d.rep_year,
            d.rep_month)AS dob
WHERE bob.rep_month = cob.rep_month
  AND bob.rep_year=cob.rep_year
  AND bob.rep_year=dob.rep_year
  AND cob.rep_year=dob.rep_year
  AND cob.rep_month = dob.rep_month
GROUP BY bob.rep_year,
         bob.rep_month
```

From three tables:

```
report_date [rep_id, rep_month, rep_year]
sale[sale_id,book_id,book_qty,s_date,s_price]
gift[gift_id,book_id,gQty,gDate,gPrice,gbooktype]
```

I have used this query in an application since 2011 and it was just today that I have realized a bug.

For any particular year and month, if there are no gift transactions for both gbooktype 1 and gbooktype 2, that year and month is ignored in the report summary.  I will be very grateful for any help so that even if there is gift transaction for  either booktype 1 or 2  or both a report for that month and year should be generated.  Also any query optimisation help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you build a a list of dates then LEFT OUTER JOIN the other results to this list.

You can generate a list of dates by UNIONing fixed values and adding that to a start value.

This would give you something like this (not tested)

```
SELECT month_year.aYear, month_year.aMonth, bob.salecnt, bob.Tsales, cob.Tgift, cob.TGiftSum, dob.Ttgift, dob.TtGiftSum 
FROM 
(
    SELECT YEAR(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2010-10-31', INTERVAL months_add MONTH), INTERVAL years_add YEAR)) as aYear, MONTH(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2010-10-31', INTERVAL months_add MONTH), INTERVAL years_add YEAR)) as aMonth
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) months_add
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) years_add
) AS month_year
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT b.rep_year, b.rep_month, sum(x.book_qty)as salecnt, sum(x.book_qty*x.s_price)as Tsales 
    FROM report_date b 
    LEFT JOIN sale x 
    ON  Month(x.s_Date) = b.rep_month 
    and  year(x.s_Date) = b.rep_year 
    WHERE x.s_date <=curdate() 
    and x.s_date >'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY b.rep_month, b.rep_year  
)as bob
ON bob.rep_year = month_year.aYear
AND bob.rep_month = month_year.aMonth
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT c.rep_year, c.rep_month, sum(y.gQty) as Tgift, sum(y.gQty*y.gPrice)as TGiftSum 
    From  report_date c 
    LEFT JOIN gift y 
    ON  month(y.gDate) = c.rep_month  
    AND year(y.gDate)=c.rep_year 
    WHERE  y.gbooktype =1 and y.gdate <=curdate() and y.gdate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY c.rep_year, c.rep_month 
)as cob
ON cob.rep_year = month_year.aYear
AND cob.rep_month = month_year.aMonth
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT d.rep_year, d.rep_month, sum(z.gQty) as Ttgift, sum(z.gQty*z.gprice)as TtGiftSum 
    From  report_date d 
    LEFT JOIN gift z 
    ON  month(z.gDate) = d.rep_month  
    AND year(z.gDate)=d.rep_year 
    WHERE z.gbooktype =2 and z.gdate <=curdate() and z.gDate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY d.rep_year, d.rep_month 
)as dob 
ON dob.rep_year = month_year.aYear
AND dob.rep_month = month_year.aMonth
```

depending on what your report_date table contains this can probably be simplified to:-

```
SELECT month_year.rep_year, month_year.rep_month, bob.salecnt, bob.Tsales, cob.Tgift, cob.TGiftSum, dob.Ttgift, dob.TtGiftSum 
FROM report_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(x.s_Date) AS rep_year, Month(x.s_Date) AS rep_month, sum(x.book_qty) as salecnt, sum(x.book_qty*x.s_price) as Tsales 
    FROM sale x 
    WHERE x.s_date <= curdate() 
    and x.s_date >'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month
)as bob
ON bob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND bob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(y.s_Date) AS rep_year, Month(y.s_Date) AS rep_month, sum(y.gQty) as Tgift, sum(y.gQty*y.gPrice)as TGiftSum 
    From  gift y 
    WHERE  y.gbooktype =1 
    and y.gdate <= curdate() 
    and y.gdate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month
)as cob
ON cob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND cob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT year(z.s_Date) AS rep_year, Month(z.s_Date) AS rep_month, sum(z.gQty) as Ttgift, sum(z.gQty*z.gprice)as TtGiftSum 
    From  gift z 
    WHERE z.gbooktype =2 
    and z.gdate <= curdate() 
    and z.gDate>'2010-10-31' 
    GROUP BY rep_year, rep_month 
)as dob 
ON dob.rep_year = report_date.rep_year
AND dob.rep_month = report_date.rep_month
WHERE CONCAT(month_year.rep_year, month_year.rep_month) > '201010'
AND CONCAT(month_year.rep_year, month_year.rep_month) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m')
```

It may be possible to simplify this further depending on what it contains

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart I am trying to run the queries but it is reporting can not find some fields. The  report_date table  contains rep_year ( years  eg 2010 ) and rep_month (months eg 02 for february, 12 for december) arranged from 01 2010  to 12 2016

Comment: Can you set up an SQL fiddle with some sample data so I can test it please.

Comment: a little tweaking of the second one worked.  I am very impressed with the speed you were able to help without any sample data